# How to get search results using SPSearch service

Tags: web-services

I need to use a **spsearch** web service to search for a particular text and get the search results for it.Someone please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

Examples can be found here:
http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/